# How do I know the values on Qt property browser changed?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using a [Qt property browser](https://github.com/commontk/QtPropertyBrowser) widget. I'm creating all the values of the property grid automatically using the moc but  I didn't find how to make the values entered in the property grid be set automatically in my class instance? is there any sginal where I can know that?

I creating the property grid like this:

```
    QWidget *w = new QWidget();
    Foo *o = new Foo();
    QtBoolPropertyManager *boolManager = new QtBoolPropertyManager(w);
    QtIntPropertyManager *intManager = new QtIntPropertyManager(w);
    QtStringPropertyManager *stringManager = new QtStringPropertyManager(w);
    QtGroupPropertyManager *groupManager = new QtGroupPropertyManager(w);

    const QMetaObject *meta = o->metaObject();
    const QString className = meta->className();
    QMap<QString, PropManager*> dic;
    QtProperty *root = groupManager->addProperty(className);

    for(int i = meta->propertyOffset(); i < meta->propertyCount(); ++i)
    {
        QMetaProperty metaProp = meta->property(i);
        const QString name = metaProp.name();
        QVariant value = metaProp.read(o);
        QVariant::Type t = metaProp.type();
        QtProperty *prop = NULL;
        PropManager *propMan = NULL;

        switch(t)
        {
            case QVariant::Int:
            {
                prop = intManager->addProperty(name);
                root->addSubProperty(prop);
                intManager->setValue(prop, value.toInt());
                propMan = new PropManager(prop, intManager, t);
                break;
            }
            case QVariant::String:
            {
                prop = stringManager->addProperty(name);
                root->addSubProperty(prop);
                stringManager->setValue(prop, value.toString());
                propMan = new PropManager(prop, stringManager, t);
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw std::invalid_argument("unknow type");
        }

        if(prop != NULL)
            dic.insert(name, propMan);
    }

    QtCheckBoxFactory *checkBoxFactory = new QtCheckBoxFactory(w);
    QtSpinBoxFactory *spinBoxFactory = new QtSpinBoxFactory(w);
    QtLineEditFactory *lineEditFactory = new QtLineEditFactory(w);

    QtAbstractPropertyBrowser *editor = new QtTreePropertyBrowser();
    editor->setFactoryForManager(boolManager, checkBoxFactory);
    editor->setFactoryForManager(intManager, spinBoxFactory);
    editor->setFactoryForManager(stringManager, lineEditFactory);
    editor->addProperty(root);

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(w);
    layout->addWidget(editor, 1, 0);
    w->show();
```

**Foo.h** is defined like this:

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Foo() { }
    ~Foo() { }

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getA WRITE setA)
    Q_PROPERTY(int age READ getNum WRITE setNum)

    QString name;
    int age;

    QString getA() const { return name; }
    int getNum() const { return age; }
    void setA(QString a) { this->name = a; }
    void setNum(int n) { this->age = n; }
};
```

Comment: Those property managers appear to be not Qt but third-party? I wonder how many people familiar with those.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't built-in the default Qt. I add a link to the library

Comment: I am not familiar with that Property Browser, but just an FYI: The [Qtilities](https://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/) library contains a nice [PropertyBrowser](https://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/class_qtilities_1_1_core_gui_1_1_object_property_browser.html) that I have used in the past.

Comment: @TheBadger: It appear that this library does use the same one I'm trying to use... still I didn't find the documentation of the singals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution:

I found `propertyChanged()` from `QtAbstractPropertyManager` but this does raise every time a single character is edited. I'd like to have an slot where this is fired when the user is done with the editing.